# Angular guards vinculado a variables

Tags: angular, typescript

estoy intentando en mi Guard de Angular hacer que devuelva true cuando mi usuario está registrado en la Base de datos, lo que me gustaría es mirar yo si está registrado y poder activar "manualemente" el guard usando un booleano.

Mi guard (no tiene nada en especial):

```
export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth:LoginComponent){}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return true;
  }

}
```

Mi código:

```
export class LoginComponent{

  constructor(public conexion:ConexionBDService, public router:Router) {}

  loginUser(form:NgForm){
    let respuesta= this.conexion.login(form.value.user, form.value.password).subscribe(
      response=> {
        if(response[1]["Rol"]=="Programador"){
          //Aquí quiero activar mi guard
          this.router.navigate([]);
        }
      }
    );
  };

}
```

Mis rutas:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "xxxxx", component: xxxxx},  
  {path: "xxxxx", component: xxxxx},
  {path: "adminPanel", component: PanelDeGestionComponent, canActivate: [AdminAuthGuard]},
  {path: "**", pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'xxxx'}
];
```

Como habéis visto la idea es cambiarlo una vez me registre desde el formulario, si existe en la BD, y a ser posible luego desconectarme claro, alguna idea?

Comment: los guards se ejecutan en entre las redirecciones. Si el `canActivate` devuelve `true` pues se carga el componente de esa ruta sino pues no lo carga. En tu caso si el login es correcto y quieres redirigr  al `adminPanel` pues haz un redirect `this.router.navigate(["adminPanel"]);` y en esta redireccion ya se ejecutará el guard que has definido.

Comment: No acabo de entender la duda: el guard tiene que comprobar que el usuario tiene "permiso" para pasar a esa nueva URL, pero la comprobación será la que tú quieras. Por ejemplo, tu login podría recibir como respuesta un token de acceso. Si tienes un token pasas, si no lo tienes no pasas

Comment: Pero de esa forma no se bloquea la URL, si no uso el guard y alguien le da por entrar por URL puede pasar sin problemas

Comment: No, la aplicación detectará que no tiene permisos y denegará el acceso (no cargará la vista)

Comment: Eso si está siempre en return false... pero yo necesitaría por lo que veo un  this.router.navigate(["adminPanel"]).params({permisos: "true"}), por ejemplo ME LO HE INVENTADO xD, necesito pasar un parámetro al router.navigate, y cogerlo por el canActivate:[AdminAuthGuard('parametro')] entonces ya podría tener una variable en el constructor del guard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma habitual de trabajar con los *Guards* es algo así:

- Tienes un componente `LoginComponent` que pide un usuario y password. Cuando el usuario los introduce, se hace una petición de login al backend.
- Cuando el backend responde con un OK, incluye un token en la respuesta (ya sea en el cuerpo o como una cabecera). Lees el token y lo guardas usando un servicio `AuthenticationService` (el servicio puede guardar el token como una propiedad o puede usar el `localStorage`, eso ya es decisión tuya).
- Cuando el usuario intenta navegar, tienes un Guard tal que así:

  ```
  export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
      if (this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
        // logged
        return true;
      }
      // not logged
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
      return false;
    }
  }
  ```

Como ves, la variable que quieres pasarle se obtiene de un servicio, que guarda el estado del usuario. No necesitas pasar nada por la URL.

Una ventaja es que ese mismo servicio puedes usarlo para añadir el token en cada petición posterior usando un HTTP interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthenticationService,
    private layoutService: LayoutService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
```